# Limit of indeteminate form $1^{(∞)}$

Tags: limits, functions, exponential-function

If we consider the function $f(x)=[(ax+1)/(bx+2)]^{x}$ where $a,\,b >0$ and $a<b,\,$ then we have to find $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$

I tried as follows][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWtS3.jpg)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWtS3.jpg]

But at end I got stuck .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equations with messy powers are usually dealt with better by taking logs of everything in sight.

So instead of looking for $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$, look for $\lim_{x \to \infty} log(f(x))$  Once you know that, you can easily find the original limit easily.

It is easy to start.

$$\begin{align}\log(f(x)) &= \log((\frac{ax + 1}{bx + 2})^x) \\
&= x \log(\frac{ax + 1}{bx + 2}) \\
&= x (log(ax + 1) - log(bx + 2))\end{align}$$.

Now we'd prefer to see something like $log(ax) - log(bx)$ but we have something messier.  So let's rearrange to get that and a hopefully small error term.

$$\begin{align}\log(f(x)) &= x (log(ax + 1) - log(bx + 2))\\
&= x (log((ax + 1)\frac{ax}{ax} - log((bx+2)\frac{bx}{bx})\\
&= x (log(ax(1 + \frac{1}{ax})) - log(bx(1 + \frac{2}{bx})))\\
&= x (log(a) + log(x) + log(1 + \frac{1}{ax}) - (log(b) + log(x) + log(1 + \frac{2}{bx})))\\
&= x (log(a/b) + log(1 + \frac{1}{ax}) - log(1 + \frac{2}{bx}))\end{align}$$

And now you have 3 cases.  $a<b$, $a=b$ and $a>b$.  The first and third have obvious answers.  For the complicated middle case, you can expand the Taylor series for $\log$ around $1$.

That gives you the limit of $\log(f(x))$.  Undo the log, and you get your answer.

Comment: Why would we look for $\lim_{x \to \infty} log(f(x))$.

Comment: To get a handle on the messy power of x.

Comment: It is not necessary, at all here, to use the logarithm function.

Comment: Not necessary, but it is straightforward and reliable.  Even on expressions that were not specially set up to work out nicely.  It is even more straightforward if your toolkit includes big-O notation.

Answer (score 6):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{ax+1}{bx+2}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac ab\right)^x\left(\frac{1+\frac{1/a}{x}}{1+\frac{2/b}{x}}\right)^x \tag 1$$

Using the limit definition of the exponential function, we see that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{1+\frac{1/a}{x}}{1+\frac{2/b}{x}}\right)^x=e^{1/a-2/b}$$

However, we have

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac ab\right)^x=\begin{cases}\infty&,a>b>0\\\\0&,b>a>0\\\\1&,a=b>0\end{cases}$$

Therefore, we conclude that if $a>b>0$, then the limit is $\infty$.  If $b>a>0$, then the limit is $0$.  And if $a=b>0$, then the limit is $e^{-1/a}$.

Comment: You are concise because you start with a magic algebraic manipulation that comes out of nowhere and ends up with the end result that is almost exactly the result that I came up with.  It is not clear how you get there, or why you would aim for that form.  By contrast I showed the manipulations I did, and motivated why you'd want to do them.  It is very concise to not show your work.  Both solutions are correct.

Comment: @btilly Do you really consider factoring $ax$ and $bx$ as "magic algebraic manipulation?"  That is material taught in junior high school.  And it is a curious and audacious statement given your unnecessary (we don't need to introduce logs here at all!), lengthy, and as of now, incomplete development.

Answer (score -1):

In any situation with this indeterminant form, I always use log and L'Hopital. First, consider $\lim\log (f (x)) $ instead. We're now looking at $\lim x(\log (ax + 1) - \log (bx + 2))$, after applying a couple of log properties. Next, rephrase it as $\lim\frac {\log (ax +1) - \log (bx +2)}{1/x} $. This has form 0/0, so L'Hopital's rule applies.